# "should be accessed in a static way"

Tags: java

I have a class with a probably unnecessarily cumbersome name, that contains a lot of static methods I use elsewhere.

Rather than fill my code with a lot of

```
VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName.doThingFoo();
VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName.doThingBar();
VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName.doThingEgg();
VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName.doThingSpam();
```

I would rather have

```
VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName thing = new VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName();
thing.doThingFoo();
thing.doThingBar();
thing.doThingEgg();
thing.doThingSpam();
```

However, this gets the warning

```
"the static method doThingFoo() should be accessed in a static way."
```

I know there are multiple solutions here.  Use better class names.  Make it not static.  Ignore it because it's just a warning.

But I don't actually think it should be a warning.  What harm does doing it this way cause?  Is there a more elegant/correct way to make my code less clunky that isn't one of the above solutions?

NOTE: I suspect this might warrant the `coding-style` tag and therefore be considered off-topic and get rejected.  I was thinking there's room here for a question like this, however, so I leave it up to y'all.

Comment: How about changing the `VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName` class?

Comment: `thing.doThing...()` suggests that `doThing....()` does something with `thing` or at least reads values from `thing`. Thus, this call is at least misleading. I have to agree with @Psychotechnopath that renaming `VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName` is a more viable option.

Comment: How about static imports of the methods?

Comment: Bit of a hack but with some modification you could chain calls like this: https://ideone.com/8LlGvO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not technically *harmful* because it technically *works*, the problem with this is it is misleading, and any values that the instance `thing` contains, do not actually matter at all for the results of the methods.

**Typical Java Convention:**

When accessing a method through an **instance**, one would expect the result to be ***dependent*** on the values of the instance.

When accessing a method through a **Class name**, one would expect the result to be ***independent*** of the values of any instance.

**Your way:**

You are accessing a method through an **instance** and expecting it to be ***independent*** of any instance.

So why use an instance for an instance independent method?  That is why it is misleading.  I would suggest attempting to shorten the class name rather than accessing `static` methods through an instance.

Comment: That's an excellent explanation of the problem with the misleading aspect of it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Frank Harris Just for an extra bit of info you might find interesting, you could have even used `VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName thing = null;`, and then still used the methods with a `null` `thing`, which can demonstrate how weird doing this can be.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the `VeryUnnecessarilyLongCumbersomeName` class?

Static methods are there to be used *without* instances. They are meant to be used if you want to invoke the method without first initializing a class. The downside of using static methods is that you lose all kinds of OOP benefits; You lose virtual dispatch and subsequently polymorphism. You can never override that method in a derived class. Of course you can declare a `new (static)` method in a derived class, but any code that accesses it has to be aware of the entire class hierarchy and do explicit checking and casting, which is precisely what OO is supposed to avoid.

Also, it is confusing. When another programmer sees your code, he/she will think upon seeing a `static` he/she will assume that it will not require a valid instance to invoke the method.

TLDR; don't do it and stick with the best practices =)

Comment: I think that as I think about this in my case, the best practice would be to just remove it from `VULCN` and put it into a terser utility class.  Of course, I acknowledge that so long as we're talking about best practices, many would say utility classes aren't really a valid solution either :)

Comment: Yea, a utility class would do the trick of course.